# How to make a method for input validation

Tags: java, validation, loops

My professor has this thing with input and that the main can't be longer than 30 lines but he wants us to validate the input. I'm making a subclass of a rectangle so I have this in the main to get the parameters of the rectangle.

```
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Enter the X coordinate (Upper Left bound):");
   int x = input.nextInt();

   System.out.println("Enter the Y coordinate (Upper Left bound):");
   int y = input.nextInt();

   System.out.println("Enter the width of the rectangle: ");
   int width = input.nextInt();

   System.out.println("Enter the height of the rectangle: ");
   int height = input.nextInt();

   BetterRectangle rectangle = new BetterRectangle(x, y, width, height);
```

He wants us to make a method in the other class to validate using hasNextInt but I'm not sure how to implement a method that validates input that comes from the main class or would i have to move the way it gets input out of the main?

Comment: Just pass the inputs by reference or pass the inputs to a method that returns the rectangle or an exception.

Comment: add a validate method (at instance level) and then call it in the constructor of `BetterRectangle` to validate inputs

Comment: so id have to move the inputs into the class and not in the main?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can you not have a method that has the `Scanner` `input` as a parameter

```
public int getNext (Scanner input, String prompt) {

    System.out.println (prompt);

    if (input.hasNextInt ()) {
       return input.nextInt ();
    }

    // return some magic number or maybe throw exception
    return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
}
```

**Updated** for @laune excellent idea

This can be used as

```
int x = getNext (input, "Enter the X coordinate (Upper Left bound):");
int y = getNext (input, "Enter the Y coordinate (Upper Left bound):");
int w = getNext (input, "Enter the width of the rectangle: ");
int h = getNext (input, "Enter the height of the rectangle:");
```

Comment: One might go all the way and add the prompt to this method.

Comment: @laune You wish is my something or other.

Comment: how would i get the 4 different parameters though?

Comment: see my updated.  This method could be in your `main` class or even a static method in your `BetterRectangle` class

Comment: I don't know if you'll still see this or not but it doesnt let me use the method in the main of the tester class, it says the method doesnt exist

Comment: ^ as a static method